# ImageView in fragment giving null

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have this code inside onCreateView in a fragment:

```
star = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.heart);
    star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"the star was clicked",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and it's giving null pointer exception. Anyone has any idea of what could it be ?

EDIT: I am editing because the answers didn't make it clear how to  resolve the issue. The problem is that rootView, the view I am inflating, is a custom list view, on which I later inflate layout item_row to define a single row in the view. The heart id is defined in this item_row but I am trying to access it from the rootView which is not possbile of course. So could anyone provide me an example of how could I do it ?

Comment: I tried with getActivity() instead of rootView but that won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.heart`  does not belong to `rootView`. It means that is not declared inside the layout you inflated inside your `onCreateView`.

Comment: How can I get it then? Since it is in another layout called item_row which is used for a listview ( the rootView ).

Comment: open the layout and declare an ImageView with id id heart

Comment: I should add the same one from the item_row layout ?

Comment: You should add the objects you need where yo do need them

Comment: I explained the structure, I have a listview in rootView but then I inflate each list item separately. So the heart is defined in my item layout not in the rootView. How can I do this ?

Comment: I see.. but then you probably need to move the onClickListener logic inside the getView method of your custom adapter

Comment: I thought so, but would that make any sense? That method is called when the list is built. I don't think it can work like so.

Comment: What is the logic? The getView method is called by the adapter to populate the list view with a list of items. Once the list is populated how could I ever call that method ?

Comment: well you interact with the view on the screen, and view itself stores a reference to the onClickLister

Comment: That worked :) Now from the View v that I receive in input in the onClick listener, how do I get the list item position ?

Comment: view has the method setTag. Use it to set as tag the list's item and retrieve it like v.getTag(). You need to cast it to the correct object

Answer (score 3):

I am doing the same thing. Here is an example that works. Make sure the View you are trying to access has an id defined in the layout you are inflating. In my example R.layout.lesson_video_fragment has an ImageView defined in with the ID R.id.lesson_video.

layout file (lesson_video_fragment.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/lesson_video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="Video"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

</LinearLayout>


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_video_fragment, container, false);

    videoImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.lesson_video);

    videoImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //do your thing
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Would that refer to the one in the other layout ?

Comment: This helped! 
I was using:
    ImageView image = 
        (ImageView) getView.findViewById(R.id.user_image); Changing getView() to view (the actual variable assigned to the inflated View) solved the problem. Thanks!